# Remove a given character from a string without using replace()?

Tags: javascript

Is this the right way to  remove a given character from String?

```js
////not using replace method
function removeChar(str1, s) {
  let temp  = str1.split('')
  let temp2 = []
  for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    if (temp[i] != s) {
      temp2.push(temp[i])
    }
  }
  console.log(temp2.join(''));
}

removeChar("Hello","l")
```

Comment: what do you mean by "right way" ? If it works, what is the issue ? You can use the replace method too

Comment: Yes this is the right function for remove element from string

Comment: I made you a snippet. I removed the escape characters to make a [mcve]

Comment: no, it is not. Try it with `remove("Hello ", "")`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
function removeChar(str1, s) {
    return str1.split(s).join('')
}
```

Comment: They can, but is that the answer to this strange question`?

Answer (score 0):

this is another solution without `replace()`

```
const removeChar = (word, letter) => word.split("").filter(v => v !== letter).join("");
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the inbuilt replace function of javascript.

`newString = oldString.replace(characterToBeReplaced, '');`

Comment: The can do that, but is that the answer to this strange question? `without using replace`